# How can I access an Apps Script variable in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, url

I have a web app deployed on Google Apps Script that generates a Google Doc according to certain specifications and returns a URL that when searched, downloads a pdf version of the Google Doc. The URL is outputted as raw text using the following command:

```
return function doGet(e) {
  var doc_id = e.parameter.doc_id;
  var digits = e.parameter.digits;
  var listOfNums = e.parameters.listOfNums.join();
  const slice = listOfNums.slice(1, -1);
  listOfNums = slice.split(", ");
  var url = createDocument(doc_id, listOfNums, digits)

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(url).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

How can I access this URL in Python?

```
        listOfNums, answers = numGenerator(digit)
        id_num = insertAnswers(db, table, answers)
        print("processing ", id_num, digit)
        print(url.format(id_num, listOfNums, digit))
        response = requests.get(url.format(id_num, listOfNums, digit))
        print("file generated")
        print(response.content)
        response = requests.get(response.content)
        print("file downloaded")
        with open("worksheet{}.pdf".format(id_num), "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

I tried to use response.content above, but that gave me the following error:

```
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
```

Comment: The Google Apps Script code is incomplete. Are you using a doGet or a doPost function?

Comment: I'm using a doGet(e), I've uploaded the full function above